# Tracking App is closed after i tap it but still running on background i want it to stay in Main Activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am making and App related to Tracking its working perfectly put the problem is it closes after I tap it though it is still working on background and providing data perfectly I want it to stay in Main Activity because I want add more features in app I am a little new coding sorry if my problem turns out to be simple and thank you in advance for help

Someone Asked if app crashes no it doesn't crash it works like it supposes to it just runs on background

[As You can see there is no app shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvsC8.png)

That's how I want it to work so even if someone closes app tracking will still be active unless someone tabs app icon on notification bar pic of that below

[Now if you tap on this then app stops tracking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9yiJ.png)

**Main Activity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            finish();
        }


        int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);


        if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startTrackerService();
        } else {


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[]
            grantResults) {


        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST && grantResults.length == 1
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            startTrackerService();
        } else {


            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable location services to allow GPS tracking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    private void startTrackerService() {
        startService(new Intent(this, TrackingService.class));


        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS tracking enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

**Tracking Service**

```
    public class TrackingService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = TrackingService.class.getSimpleName();
    public TrackingService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        buildNotification();
        loginToFirebase();
    }


    private void buildNotification() {
        String stop = "stop";
        registerReceiver(stopReceiver, new IntentFilter(stop));
        PendingIntent broadcastIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 0, new Intent(stop), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.tracking_enabled_notif))


                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentIntent(broadcastIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tracking_enabled);
        startForeground(1, builder.build());
    }

    protected BroadcastReceiver stopReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


            unregisterReceiver(stopReceiver);


            stopSelf();
        }
    };

    private void loginToFirebase() {


        String email = getString(R.string.test_email);
        String password = getString(R.string.test_password);


        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {


                if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                    requestLocationUpdates();
                } else {


                    Log.d(TAG, "Firebase authentication failed");
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void requestLocationUpdates() {
        LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();


        request.setInterval(10000);


        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        FusedLocationProviderClient client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        final String path = getString(R.string.firebase_path);
        int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);


        if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            client.requestLocationUpdates(request, new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {


                    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(path);
                    Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                    if (location != null) {


                        ref.setValue(location);
                    }
                }
            }, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**Information for Quick Test of App**

```
In Firebase Project on Authentication tab.
Select “Set up sign-in method.”
Choose “Email/password” and then push the slider into the “On” position. Click “Save.”
Select the “Users” tab and then click “Add User.”
Enter the email and password for the test user; I’m opting for test@test.com and testpassword.
Click “Add User.”
```

**Android Studio what I did for Notifications icons **

```
Control-click your project’s “res/drawable” folder and then select New > Image Asset.
Open the “Icon Type” dropdown and then select “Notification Icons.”
Click the little button that appears alongside the “Clip Art” label.
Choose the icon you want to use; I’m opting for “My Location.” Click “OK.”
Name this icon “tracking_enabled,” and then click “Next.”
Check the information on the subsequent screen, and then click “Finish.”

**Dependencies**

dependencies {
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
}
```

**Manifest**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**String**

```
    <string name="tracking_enabled_notif">Tracking is currently enabled. Tap to cancel.</string>
<string name="test_email">test@test.com</string>
<string name="test_password">testpassword</string>
<string name="firebase_path">location</string>
```

Ok I think I made Title summary and Provided Minimal Testing code if I still missed something Sorry for that I hope you guys can help me I will be really grateful thank you in advance xD

Comment: Tap on `back` button or? App crashes?

Comment: no it doesn't crash when u start app by pressing icon it just opens and closes and runs on background and provides data in firebase perfectly it just doesn't stay on app or in main Activity and u can cancel tracking service by just tapping on App in Notification bar and then it stops tracking otherwise it keeps updating data on firebase perfectly

Comment: Try to remove `finish();` method from your `MainActivity`

Comment: Sure no problem you are welcome.

Comment: thanks I am starting to think I am blind :'(

Comment: Ah don't worry those kind of errors are not something you need to worry about when you are beginner. That's just happen.

Comment: The Documentation you provided is amazing I got a little bit of it I just hope I can get it all an implement it developer.android.com is a very scary site at least for me xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        finish();
    }
```

In this part of code you are checking status of given provider which is in your case GPS Provider and if it returns `false` than `finish();` method is called and your `MainActivity` finishes. But since you are starting services just below app runs service as well that is why your are getting info on Firebase even app is closed. Not sure why you are calling `finish();` but I think that is the problem.

Also check changes and limitations which are introduced in Android Oreo and one particularly will impact your app:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes

Comment: Yes because app is killed so try with implementing or `overriding` this method in your `services` class:
`@Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            return START_STICKY;
        }`
Which should restart `service` after app is killed.